# Dojo // dijit.form.FilteringSelect // How to add a class to a <select> field in Dojo's filter Select

Tags: html, css, select, dojo, filtering

I am trying to add a class to some of my dojo.filterselect in order to color them in Blue. 
Does anyone know how to do that?

thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug to find which CSS filteringselect uses, and override the default color or add your color